# Unclear use of // in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Let's look at the following XML file:

```
<a>
  <b w="w">
    <b1 x="x" />
    <b2 y="y" />
  </b>
</a>
```

The following XPath query returns elements `b1` and `b2`:

```
/*/*//*
```

From this I conclude that `//*` means to select all elements that are descendants of `b` **not including `b` itself**.

However the following XPath query returns attributes `w`, `x`, `y`:

```
/*/*//@*
```

So from this I conclude that `//@*` means to select all attributes that appear in descendants of `b` **including `b` itself**.

How does this work? Does `//` work differently for elements vs attributes, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`

`/*` meanwhile identifies all child nodes from the current position.

Starting from the root, `/*/*//` therefore moves us to `<a>` (child of root) and then to `<b>` (all children of that `<a>` being that single `<b>`) and then selects `descendant-or-self::node()`, which is to say, `<b>`, `<b1>` and `<b2>`.

It's from that starting point of `<b>`, `<b1>` and `<b2>` matched by `/*/*//` that your two paths differ.

`/*/*//*` matches all child nodes of those nodes. Since `<b1>` and `<b2>` don't have child nodes, this matches only the child nodes of `<b>`: `<b1>` and `<b2>`.

`/*/*//@*` matches all attributes of those nodes. Since `<b>`, `<b1>` and `<b2>` all have attributes, all of those attributes are matched.

> From this I conclude that `//*` means to select all elements that are descendants of `b` *not including `b` itself*.

Yes, but only indirectly. It means "select all elements that are descendants of `b` **including** `b` itself, and **then** find their children". This amounts to "all descendants of `b` but not `b`" but it went through "including `b`" to get there.

Comment: Thanks Jon (and collapsar)! Very clearly explained :)

Answer (score 2):

The apparent contradiction stems from the interpretations of the shorthand notation for xpath expressions.

`//` in xpath expressions is a shorthand for the xpath axis `//descendant-or-self::node()/`. Specifying an *element*  in an xpath, eg. by its tag name  actually queries the element on the `child` axis.

The `child` axis does not apply when querying attributes - `@` represents its own axis, namely `attributes`.

Therefore the matching appears to include one more level in the tre representation.